# jquery bootstrap model is not a function

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, drupal-7

I am trying to open a bootstrap modal on click. I am using drupal 7 and the latest version of bootstrap. 4.3.1

JS File

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($){
 $(function() {
  $('#myButton').click(function (e) {
    console.log('button clicked');
    $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

HTML

```
<div id='exampleModal'>
```

When i run this I get

```
"Uncaught TypeError: $(...)modal is not a function
```

How can i successfully open this modal?

Answer (score 1):

1. As you have mentioned that you were using `Bootstrap4`,you dont need `onclick` function. You can use `data-target="#exampleModal"` on your button to open the modal with the particular `id` with `class="modal"`. 
   Below is the example for same. [Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_modal.asp)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Modal Example</h2>
    <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div class="modal" id="myModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

          <!-- Modal Header -->
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          </div>

          <!-- Modal body -->
          <div class="modal-body">
            Modal body..
          </div>

          <!-- Modal footer -->
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

2.Using `click` function

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.btn-primary').click(function() {
    $('#exampleModal').modal('show');
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Modal Example</h2>
    <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
    Open modal
  </button>

    <!-- The Modal -->
    <div class="modal" id="exampleModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

          <!-- Modal Header -->
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          </div>

          <!-- Modal body -->
          <div class="modal-body">
            Modal body..
          </div>

          <!-- Modal footer -->
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

check that jQuery is not included twice.

check that bootstrap's javascript is loaded before calling Modal

wrap your code in

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
   //your code
}
```

just to be sure

Comment: please pay attention $(document).on( "ready", handler ), deprecated as of jQuery 1.8 . You should use $( handler ) instead